# dd: Trying to recover my file system

Tags: grub2, dd

ubuntu: 14.04

By mistake I ran the following command

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda2 bs=1024 count=1
```

and now grub is unable to recognize file system and so the linux is not starting. I think I have written 0s in  my hard disk as per the above commands instead of SD card (my actual intention). 
Is there a way I can undo this?

I am able boot my system using a live USB and able to do fdisk etc.

**Info**

```
 root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x77777777

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63    61240297    30620117+  83  Linux
/dev/sda2        61241342   312560639   125659649    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       122479623   183719339    30619858+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       183719403   250276634    33278616    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda7       250276698   312560639    31141971    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda8        61241344    65239039     1998848   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda9        65241088   122479369    28619141   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/sdb: 16.0 GB, 16008609792 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1946 cylinders, total 31266816 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *         192    31266815    15633312    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu#
```

Right now I have connected my live USB so you see sdb1 above.

Comment: Try `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt` and then `ls /mnt`

Comment: @Helio  got this error mount: you must specify the filesystem type

Comment: Your solution may be `testdisk`